# Is $p \equiv q\pmod{15}$ the same as $p\equiv q\pmod{5}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Let $p$ and $q$ be prime. If $p\equiv q \pmod{15}$, then is it true to say they are congruent mod $5$?

I figure I could say $p - q \equiv 0 \pmod{15}$, so $p\equiv q \pmod{5}$, but what throws me off is when we let $p = 37$ and $q = 7$.

So $37\equiv 7 \pmod{15}$, but $37\equiv 2 \pmod{5}$ which disproves this, doesn’t it? Or is it legal to just say $37\equiv 7 \pmod{5}$ is the same as $37\equiv 2 \pmod{5}$ since $7\equiv 2 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: $7\equiv 2\pmod {5}$, but $7\not\equiv 2\pmod {15}$.

Comment: Yes, it is "legal" to say it, from the basic definition of congruence.

Comment: $p\equiv q\pmod {15}\,\Leftrightarrow\, 15\mid p-q\,\Rightarrow\,5\mid p-q\,\Leftrightarrow\, p\equiv q\pmod {5}$. So $p\equiv q\pmod {15}\,\Rightarrow\, p\equiv q\pmod {5}$, but it's not true the other way around, so they're not the same.

Comment: So basically, if p = q mod 15, then they are congruent mod 5. But being congruent mod 5 does not imply they are congruent mod 15.

Comment: @user2327195 yes.

Comment: $p=q+15n$ is the same as $p=q+5(3n)$. If $p=q+5m$ then $m=3r+s$  with $s\in \{0,1,2\}$ then $p=q+15r+5s$ where $5s=0,5,10$.

Comment: Rephrase your question as asking if the following statement is true: "A number is divisible by $15$ if and only if it is divisible by $5$". I think the solution should be most obvious, now :)

Comment: Definition: $a\equiv b\pmod {n}\,\Leftrightarrow\, n\mid a-b$. Or i.e. $a,b$ leave the same remainders when divided by $n$.  

So in your case indeed $37\equiv 7\pmod {5}$, since $5\mid 30=37-7$. Both $37,7$ leave the same remainders, namely $2$, when divided by $5$. Both $37,7$ belong to the same equivalence classes modulo $5$ ($a\equiv b\pmod {n}$ is an equivalence relation (since $a\equiv a$ and $a\equiv b\,\Leftrightarrow\, b\equiv a$ and $a\equiv b,\:b\equiv a\,\Rightarrow\, a\equiv c$), so we can divide the values $a\bmod{n}$ into equivalence classes).

Comment: The question in your title and the question in your question are subtly different: your title asks if being equivalent mod 15 is _the same_ as being equivalent mod 5, whereas the text of the question only asks if one implies the other.  The latter is true, but the former is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be confusing the notion of modular equivalence in mathematics with the `mod` *operator* in computer programming; while the two are closely related, they're not quite the same thing.  The `mod` operator is actually a *function*, one that takes two numbers (a value and a modulus) and returns the remainder from dividing the value by the modulus; for instance, we say that `22 mod 5 = 2`.  Here (ignoring negative numbers), `a mod n = b` means that c is a number between $0$ and $n-1$ and that $a-b$ is a multiple of $n$.

Mathematically, though, mod is generally used for what's known as an *equivalence relation*; we say that $a\equiv b\pmod n$ if and only if $a-b$ is a multiple of $n$.  There's no requirement that $b$ be less than $n$; it's true that $22\equiv 2\pmod 5$, but it's also true that $22\equiv 37\pmod 5$ (since $22-37=-15$ is a multiple of $5$, or even that $22\equiv -13\pmod 5$ (since $22-(-13)=35$ is a multiple of $5$).  The two can be related back and forth: in one direction we have $a\equiv b\pmod n$ if and only if $a$ `mod` $n = b$ `mod` $n$, and going the other way the value of $a$ `mod` $n$ is the *unique* number $b$ (can you see why it's unique?) such that $a\equiv b\pmod n$ and $0\leq b\leq n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

I find it helpful to take questions like these out of a congruence relation to understand them sometimes. 
$p\equiv q\pmod{15}$ just means $p=q+15n$ for some integer $n$. This can now be rewritten as $p=q+5(3n)$. Since $3n$ is clearly also an integer, we can now put this back into a congruence relation $p\equiv q\pmod{5}$. Therefore it is true that $p\equiv q\pmod{15}$ implies $p\equiv q\pmod{5}$.

Also, you mentioned using the form $p-q\equiv0\pmod{15}$. I find this form is always preferable because it removes any confusion over the residue classes. Using your example where $p=37$ and $q=7$, it can be seen that $37-7=30\equiv 0\pmod{15}$ and $37-7=30\equiv 0\pmod{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

$p \equiv q \bmod{15} \iff 15 \mid (p-q) \iff 5 \mid (p-q)$ and $3 \mid (p-q) \iff p \equiv q \bmod{3}$ and $p \equiv q \bmod{5}$.